# sqlalchemy join with sum and count of grouped rows

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Hi i am working on a little prediction game in flask with flask-sqlalchemy I have a User Model:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    nick = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    bets = relationship('Bet', backref=backref("user"))
```

and my Bet model

```
class Bet(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    uid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    matchid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('match.id'))
    points = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

Both are not the full classes but it should do it for the question. A user can gather points for predicting the match outcome and gets different amount of points for predicting the exact outcome, the winner or the difference.
I now want to have a list of the top users, where i have to sum up the points which i'm doing via

```
toplist = db.session.query(User.nick, func.sum(Bet.points)).\
    join(User.bets).group_by(Bet.uid).order_by(func.sum(Bet.points).desc()).all()
```

This works quite good, now there maybe the case that two players have the same sum of points. In this case the amount of correct predictions (rewarded with 3 points) would define the winner. I can get this list by

```
tophits = db.session.query(User.nick, func.count(Bet.points)).\
            join(User.bets).filter_by(points=3).all()
```

They both work well, but I think there has to be a way to get both querys together and get a table with username, points and "hitcount". I've done that before in SQL but i am not that familiar with SQLAlchemy and thought knots in my brain. How can I get both queries in one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the query for `tophits` just replace the `COUNT/filter_by` construct with equivalent `SUM(CASE(..))` without `filter` so that the `WHERE` clause for both is the same. The code below should do it:

```
total_points = func.sum(Bet.points).label("total_points")
total_hits = func.sum(case(value=Bet.points, whens={3: 1}, else_=0)).label("total_hits")
q = (session.query(
        User.nick,
        total_points,
        total_hits,
        )
    .join(User.bets)
    .group_by(User.nick)
    .order_by(total_points.desc())
    .order_by(total_hits.desc())
    )
```

---

Note that i changed a group_by clause to use the column which is in SELECT, as some database engines might complain otherwise. But you do not need to do it.

Comment: it's pretty near but it sums up all points for every user, if user1 has two bets poth 3 points, and user2 has two bets one 2 points one 1 points, the output is [(u'user1',9,2),(u'user2',9,2)]

Comment: So, this works: ¸toplist = db.session.query(User.nick, func.sum(Bet.points), func.sum(case(value=Bet.points, whens={3: 1}, else_=0))).\
join(User.bets).group_by(Bet.uid).order_by(func.sum(Bet.points).desc()).all()¸

Comment: You are right: missed `join(User.bets)` (added to the answer).

Comment: ... do not forget to add second `order_by`